# How to get chrome to use more CPU power

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, p5.js

I made a NeroEvolution based AI that plays snake in p5.js, and in order to try and speed up the training I am trying to get many game cycles per frame, but chrome can't keep up. Is there any way I can allow chrome to use more CPU horsepower? Or is there any way to run p5.js without a browser? Chrome is currently only using 14% of my CPU.

Comment: Your limit of 14% is likely from max'ing out one thread/core.  It is a lot of work but parallelization with Web Workers may offer speedup for your AI training.  Likely very difficult to implement, if possible at all for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look up Electron if you want to make Javascript based Desktop apps. But be aware that it's still running chromium behind the scenes